# Отправка данных на сервер без данных в форме

Tags: javascript, form

Хочу передать данные из переменных JS в форму или без нее, если возможно, так же как это было бы с `input form='.
То есть, нужно передать через GET данные переменных с перезагрузкой страницы.

Comment: `window.location = window.location` перезагрузит страницу

Comment: @ThisMan а чё не `window.location.reload()` тогда уж

Comment: @andreymal как душе угодно)

Comment: Собственно, у меня идет выборка товаров, данные идут в контроллер, который выбирает из БД товары. И нужно передвать get параметры фильтров и заново зайти в контроллер типо